# Rails 4 AJAX login form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I try make a AJAX login form using parameter **remote** in login form. But after login i can't redirect user to home page. But redirection does not work. My code below:

```
  class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def create
    user = User.find_by_login(params[:login])
    respond_to do |format|
        if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
        format.html { redirect_to index_path }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js { redirect_to index_path }
        else
        format.html { redirect_to login_url, alert: "Wrong login or password!" }
        format.json {render json: "Wrong login or password", status: :unprocessable_entity}
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

<!-- app/view/session/new.html.erb -->
<%= form_tag(nil, remote: true) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :login, params[:login] %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
<% end %>

<!-- app/view/session/create.js.erb -->
$(document).window.location.replace("http://hardrate.net");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
format.js { redirect_to index_path }
```

for

```
format.js
```

Edit:

Also change

```
$(document).window.location.replace("http://hardrate.net");
```

for

```
window.location.replace("http://hardrate.net");
```

or

```
window.location.href = "http://hardrate.net";
```